# Свойства файла как в windows C#

Tags: c#, файлы

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, как можно посмотреть свойства файла на подобии тех, что появляются в окошке, когда жмешь правой кнопкой мыши по файлу, выбираешь там строчку "свойства" и потом появляется то самое окошко?

Сейчас я использую `FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo`, но конечный результат, мягко говоря, меня не радует - практически все свойства пустые (см. скриншот). 
Свойства менять не надо, только прочитать и вывести, допустим, в текстовые поля.
Язык C#. Работаю, если что, с торрент-файлами.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Это всё умеет Windows Shell, поэтому не будем изобретать велосипед, а спросим у неё. Нам понадобится подключить в References COM-объект Shell32 (он называется «Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation»):

[image: о боже, COM, он ещё не умер?]

После этого пишем следующий код:

```
[STAThread] // нужно для консольных приложений, иначе COM не будет работать
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"D:\IMG_2111.JPG"; // к примеру
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    var file = Path.GetFileName(path);

    var shell = new Shell32.Shell();
    var folder = shell.NameSpace(dir);
    var folderItem = folder.ParseName(file);

    var names =
        (from idx in Enumerable.Range(0, short.MaxValue)
         let key = folder.GetDetailsOf(null, idx)
         where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)
         select (idx, key)).ToDictionary(p => p.idx, p => p.key);

    var properties =
        (from idx in names.Keys
         orderby idx
         let value = folder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, idx)
         where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
         select (name: names[idx], value)).ToList();

    foreach (var kvp in properties)
        Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.name}: {kvp.value}");
}
```

Если не хочется подключать COM-объект статически, через References, вы можете подключить его в рантайме:

```
var shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
var folder = shell.NameSpace(dir);
var folderItem = folder.ParseName(file);

var names =
    (from idx in Enumerable.Range(0, short.MaxValue)
     let key = (string)folder.GetDetailsOf(null, idx) // пришлось вставить cast
     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)
     select (idx, key)).ToDictionary(p => p.idx, p => p.key);

var properties =
    (from idx in names.Keys
     orderby idx
     let value = (string)folder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, idx) // пришлось вставить cast
     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
     select (name: names[idx], value)).ToList();
```

(Ещё можно описать интерфейсы через `[ComImport] [InterfaceType(...)]`, чтобы не работать через `dynamic`, но мне лень.)

У меня получился такой вот результат. Для картинки:

```
Имени: IMG_2111.JPG
Размера: 1,22 МБ
Тип элемента: JPG Image
Дата изменения: 03.02.2018 15:12
Дата создания: 03.02.2018 15:12
Дата доступа: 03.02.2018 15:12
Атрибуты: A
Распознанный тип: Изображение
Владелец: Hive\VladD
Вид: Изображение
Дата съемки: ‎22.‎08.‎2016 ‏‎15:19
Оценка: Без оценки
Камера, модель: iPhone 6s
Размеры: ‪2576 x 1920‬
Камера, изготовитель: Apple
Имя программы: 9.3.4
Компьютер: HIVE (этот компьютер)
Расширение: .JPG
Имя файла: IMG_2111.JPG
Глубина цвета: 24
Горизонтальное разрешение: ‎72 точек на дюйм
Ширина: ‎2576 пикселей
Разрешение по вертикали: ‎72 точек на дюйм
Высота: ‎1920 пикселей
Общий доступ: Нет
Имя папки: D:\
Путь к папке: D:\
Расположение: D:\
Путь: D:\IMG_2111.JPG
Тип: JPG Image
Состояние ссылки: Неразрешенные
Версия EXIF: 0221
Экспокоррекция: ‎0 шаг.
Программа экспозиции: Обычный
Выдержка: ‎1/444 с.
Диафрагма: f/2.2
Вспышка, режим: Без вспышки, принудительно
Фокусное расстояние: ‎3 мм
Фокусное расстояние, экв. 35 мм: 31
Скорость ISO: ISO-32
Экспозамер: Усредненный
Ориентация: Обычный
Программный режим: Обычная съемка
Баланс белого: Авто
Состояние общего доступа: Общий доступ отсутствует
```

Для исполнимого файла:

```
Имени: notepad.exe
Размера: 231 КБ
Тип элемента: Приложение
Дата изменения: 29.09.2017 15:42
Дата создания: 29.09.2017 15:42
Дата доступа: 29.09.2017 15:42
Атрибуты: A
Распознанный тип: Приложение
Владелец: TrustedInstaller
Вид: Программа
Оценка: Без оценки
Авторские права: © Корпорация Майкрософт. Все права защищены.
Организация: Microsoft Corporation
Описание файла: Блокнот
Компьютер: HIVE (этот компьютер)
Расширение: .exe
Имя файла: notepad.exe
Версия файла: 6.2.16299.15
Общий доступ: Нет
Имя папки: System32
Путь к папке: C:\Windows\System32
Расположение: System32 (C:\Windows)
Путь: C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
Тип: Приложение
Язык: Русский (Россия)
Состояние ссылки: Неразрешенные
Состояние общего доступа: Общий доступ отсутствует
Название продукта: Операционная система Microsoft® Windows®
Версия продукта: 10.0.16299.15
```

Comment: А на форме этот код будет работать? Потому как на строчке select (idx, key)) ругается на последнюю скобку, а в строчке select (name: names[idx], value)).ToList(); ругается на все, кроме names.

Comment: @АндрейФедоров: А какая у вас версия Visual Studio?

Comment: У меня версия 2015 года

Comment: @АндрейФедоров: Мм.да, что ж вы на древних версиях сидите? Там этого и правда нет. Придётся заменить `select (idx, key)).ToDictionary(p => p.idx, p => p.key);` на что-то типа `select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(idx, key)).ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);`. Ну и в следующей строке аналогично.

Comment: Следующая должна быть так? select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(name:names[idx],value)).ToList(); Если да, то он почему-то value не воспринимает и пишет ошибку "спецификация поименованого аргумента должна появляться во всех указанных фиксированных аргумента".

Comment: @АндрейФедоров: Не, там `name:` не нужен, просто `names[idx]`.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72665/discussion-between---and-vladd).

Answer (score 2):

В целом для каждого формата файлов все будет по своему (ID3-теги у mp3, и другие форматы метаинформации для прочих медиафайлов нужно будет читать и парсить индивидуально), общую же информацию о файле можно получать используя класс `System.IO.FileInfo`.