# Как правильно получить значение пути для исполняемого файла

Tags: c#

Как правильно отделить путь к исполняемому файлу от аргументов командной строки, не могу обойти ошибку. Суть, есть метод, который достает все запускаемые файлы из реестра,(из определенной ветки) У меня Win 64  и в сборке проекта я убрал галочку предпочтительно 32 разрядная, в надежде чтобы все работало хорошо и для 32 и для 64 разрядов. И теперь когда я через linq достаю имена и пути  к файлу, то получается ошибка FileNotFoundException, так как вместо пути возвращается строка вида `"rundll32.exe xrWCbgnd.dll,LaunchBgTask 1"`.  Вот мой код.

```
  public  List<info> PrintKeys(string rkey)
            {


                    List<info> stroka=new List<info>();
                    string F = "Цифровая подпись найдена ";
                    string G = "Цифровая подпись корректна";
                    string G0 = "Цифровая подпись не корректна";
                    string tipzapuska = "Реестр";
                    String rp = rkey;
                    RegistryKey rk;
                    X509Certificate2 theCertificate;
                    using (rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(rp))
                    {


                        var e = rk.GetValueNames().Select(n => new
                        {
                            Name = n,
                            Value = rk.GetValue(n),
                            Exec = rk.GetValue(n).ToString()
                                .Split('"').Where(i => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(i)).First()
                        });
                        foreach (var x in e)
                        {

                            string path = x.Exec;
                            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).Split(' ')[0];
                            var file = path.Substring(0, path.IndexOf(ext) + ext.Length);




                            var icon1 = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file).ToBitmap();
                            try
                            {
                            X509Certificate theSigner = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(x.Exec);
                            theCertificate = new X509Certificate2(theSigner);
                             // проверяем на валидность
                            byte[] mashash =theCertificate.GetCertHash();// хеш из сертификата файла в sha1
                            byte[] fileSha1 = GetSha1Hash(x.Exec);// получаем хеш файла в sha1

                                // сравниваем два массива

                            bool bEqual = false;
                            if (fileSha1.Length == mashash.Length)
                            {
                                int i = 0;
                                while ((i < fileSha1.Length) && (fileSha1[i] == mashash[i]))
                                {
                                    i += 1;
                                }
                                if (i == fileSha1.Length)
                                {
                                    bEqual = true;
                                }
                            }



                                // готовим строку
                                if (bEqual)
                                {
                                    stroka.Add(new info() { A = icon1, F1 = F, G1 = G, Namefile1 = x.Name, Path1 = (string) x.Value, Company = theCertificate.Issuer,TipZapuska = tipzapuska});  
                                }
    //                           
                                stroka.Add(new info() { A = icon1, F1 = F, G1 = G0, Namefile1 = x.Name, Path1 = (string) x.Value, Company = theCertificate.Issuer, TipZapuska = tipzapuska});  



                            }
                            catch (Exception exception)
                            {

                                stroka.Add(new info() { A = icon1, F1 = "Цифровая подпись отсутсвует", G1 = "Цифровая подпись отсутсвует", Namefile1 = x.Name, Path1 = (string)x.Value, TipZapuska = tipzapuska });
                            }



                        }
                    }
                    return stroka;
                } // local mashin

 public class info
    {
        public Bitmap A { get; set; } // иконка файла
        public string Namefile1 { get; set; } //Имя исполняемого файла.
        public string C1 { get; set; } //Параметры командной строки для запуска файла.
        public string Path1 { get; set; }// путь
        public string F1 { get; set; }//Флаг наличия цифровой подписи.
        public string G1 { get; set; }//Флаг корректности цифровой подписи
        public string Company { get; set; }//Информация о компании
        public string TipZapuska { get; set; }


        public info()
        {


        }


    }
   public byte[] GetSha1Hash(string filePath)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(filePath))
            {
                SHA1 sha = new SHA1Managed();
                return sha.ComputeHash(fs).ToArray();
            }
        }
```

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight ошибка fileNotFound  .  путь у меня  не верный, исключение типа "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" в System.Drawing.dll, я пытаюсь добыть иконку для файла, но путь к файлу получается такой   path= "rundll32.exe xrWCbgnd.dll,LaunchBgTask 1", хотя мне нужен полный путь.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight а можно ли такой же метод сделать для получения именно аргументов командной строки, без пути?

Comment: Будет практически то же самое, только нужно делать Substring не между ind1 и ind2, а между ind2+1 и commandline.Length

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Скажите, а можно ли как то вытащить из самого файла исполняемого информацию о компании производителе, по типу как сделано в свойствах винды?

Comment: Посмотрите, например, здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779728/240512 Не нужно спрашивать все подряд в комментариях к одному вопросу; вместо этого создавайте новый вопрос (или спрашивайте в чате, если вопрос короткий).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очевидно, тот ключ реестра, который вы получаете, содержит не путь к файлу, а полную командную строку (с аргументами), причем пути указываются относительно системного каталога. Попробуйте пропустить через такой метод:

```
static string GetExePath(string commandline)
{            
    string exepath;

    int ind1 = commandline.IndexOf('"');
    int ind2 = commandline.IndexOf('"', ind1 + 1);

    if (ind1 < 0 && ind2 < 0) //если в строке нет кавычек, путь должен быть до первого пробела
    {
        ind1 = 0;
        ind2 = commandline.IndexOf(' ');
        if (ind2 < 0) ind2 = commandline.Length;
    }
    else //если есть кавычки - путь между первой парой кавычек
    {
        ind1 += 1;
    }
    exepath = commandline.Substring(ind1, ind2 - ind1);

    if (!System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(exepath))
    {
        exepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, exepath);
    }
    return exepath;
}
```

Comment: В вашем методе у меня вышло исключение , Необработанное исключение типа "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Длина не может быть меньше нуля. Наверное нужно сделать проверку, что если аргумент будет нулевым, то есть в командной строке больше нет ничего, то пусть так и будет

Comment: commandline "C:\\Windows\\PixArt\\PAC7302\\Monitor.exe" string   exepath null string
ind1 0 int
ind2 -1 int

Comment: Спасибо помогло, сейчас дальше буду разбираться

Comment: Делаю вот так , увы не получается  exepath = commandline.Substring(commandline.Length-ind2 + 1)

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch `commandline.Substring(ind2 + 1, commandline.Length - (ind2+1));`

Comment: так сделал,  я вижу в отладчике   CmParametrs "C:\\Windows\\system32\\xrWCbgnd.dll,LaunchBgTask 1" хотя мне нужно  вроде это как параметр xrWCbgnd.dll,LaunchBgTask 1

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Нужно еще убрать блок `if (!System.IO.Path.IsPathRooted(exepath))...`, он для аргументов не нужен

Comment: Увы не работает, убрал if,но все равно показывает полную строку