# Как получить свойства исполняемого файла

Tags: c#

подскажите,как правильно получить имя производителя исполняемого файла из свойств файла, пробую использовать вот такое решение [Тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/779648/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2-windows-c/779728#779728), но почему то я вижу только заголовки свойств но не их значения. Мне нужно получить только строку с указанием компании производителя. Заранее спасибо.Вот мой код, он без концовки, без форыча, потому как не могу достать именно параметры,а вижу только заголовки. Сморю только екзешники

```
public string GetInfoFile(string pa)
{
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> Listss=new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

    var path = pa;
    var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    var file = Path.GetFileName(path);

    var shell = new Shell32.Shell();
    var folder = shell.NameSpace(dir);
    var folderItem = folder.ParseName(file);

    var names =
        (from idx in Enumerable.Range(0, short.MaxValue)
            let key = folder.GetDetailsOf(null, idx)
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)
            select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(idx, key))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

    var properties =
        (from idx in names.Keys
            orderby idx
            let value = folder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, idx)
            where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
         select new KeyValuePair<int, string>(idx, names[idx]))
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);

    foreach (var kvp in properties)
        Listss.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);

    return Listss;
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали на разных исполняемых файлах? И покажите ваш код.

Comment: @VladD добавил код

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант - использовать класс [FileVersionInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
using System.Diagnostics;


var fvi = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(pathToExe);
Console.WriteLine(fvi.CompanyName);
Console.WriteLine(fvi.ProductName);
```

Comment: Спасибо, что что надо.