# С# Получить длительность видеофайла

Tags: c#

Каким образом можно получить длительность видеофайла в Windows с помощью C#, не используя сторонние библиотеки (обертки ffmpeg и т.п.)? Существуют ли в C# какие-нибудь специальные функции для этого, или же можно использовать какие-либо внутренние API Windows?

Comment: Ну если WMP способен открыть этот файл, значит есть соответствующий контрол, например в WPF MediaPlayer,  способный его так же открыть, из него можно длительность и узнать. Кстати, `не используя сторонние библиотеки` - почему?

Comment: В языке вообще нет функций, ни одной! Все функции в библиотеках, родных или сторонних. | Ищете описание форматов видеофайлов (а их много!), пишете код разбора заголовков этих форматов - получаете длительность.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> или же можно использовать какие-либо внутренние API Windows?

Конечно можно, и даже нужно! Если Windows умеет воспроизводить какой-либо формат видео, то и получение длительности идет в комплекте. Проще всего добраться до него, не подключая библиотек и не декларируя никаких интерфейсов DirectShow / Media Foundation можно через свойства в [Shell API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/folder). Media Foundation предоставляет провайдер со свойствами для видеофайлов, воспроизведение которых поддерживается, т.е. для тех, которые открываются в Windows Media Player. Именно благодаря этому в свойствах файла в проводнике можно посмотреть длительность, разрешение видео и др. Длительность является 27 свойством (что не документировано, но хорошо известно).

Вот так можно получить свойство через Shell API в C# (идея взята из [этого ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779728/240512)):

```
[STAThread]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string path = @"C:\Media\test.avi";
    string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
    string file = Path.GetFileName(path);

    Type shellAppType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Shell.Application");
    dynamic shell = Activator.CreateInstance(shellAppType);
    dynamic folder = shell.NameSpace(dir);
    dynamic folderItem = folder.ParseName(file);
    string value = folder.GetDetailsOf(folderItem, 27).ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("Duration: " + value);
}
```

Это выведет строку вида "Duration: 01:54:46"

Стандартно работает с форматами, поддерживаемыми [Media Foundation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/supported-media-formats-in-media-foundation), например WMV, AVI. Провайдеры для других форматов могут быть добавлены с пакетами кодеков.

Comment: Великолепно, только как это привести в var и где взять enum для второго параметра GetDetailsOf ?

Comment: И где можно почитать про COM объекты для C#? Вещь мощная, но до сей поры натыкался только на рутинные применения.

Comment: То что нужно!
В процессе поиска нашел вариант получения через WindowsMediaPlayer. В моем случае нужно получать длительность около 300 файлов, и вариант через WindowsMediaPlayer даже близко не приблизился по скорости к вашему (Люди спрашивали под вопросом, почему в приоритете были не сторонние библиотеки. Вот именно из-за возможности таких "нативных" вариантов) Большое спасибо за развернутый и подробный ответ!

Comment: @Blackmeser "привести в var" - для этого надо подключить библиотеку типов Shell API, в ответе VladD это есть в начале. "где взять enum для второго параметра GetDetailsOf" - нигде, значения не документированные, были найдены на практике перебором

Comment: @Blackmeser "где можно почитать про COM объекты для C#?" - например https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/cominterop , https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/